# Other Ways of Verifying Balanced Parenthesis?

Tags: algorithm, stack

A Classical example of how stacks are quite important is in the problem of verifying whether a string of parenthesis is balanced or not. You start with an empty stack and you keep pushing/popping elements in the stack, at the end, you check if your stack is empty, and if so return that the string is indeed balanced.

However, I am looking for other **less efficient** approaches to solve this problem. I want to show my students the usefulness of the stack data structure by first coming up with an exponential/non linear algorithm that solves the problem, then introduce the stack solution. Is anyone familiar with other methods other than the stack based approach?

Comment: What constitutes parens? Just `(` and `)`? Or are you talking all types of grouping characters, like `[,],(,),<,>,{,}`? If it's just one type, you don't even need a stack; a simple counter will do.

Comment: Type "parentheses" in the search box and look at the least upvoted answers? I assume you'll find a whole range of inefficient methods.

Comment: Here's a brand new one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083288/parenthesis-matching-algorithm-correctness

Comment: This question really belongs in [cseducators.se]. In fact, [this question](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/791/what-are-some-good-examples-of-using-a-stack-data-structure) in particular might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3):

find the last opening-parenthesizes, and look whether it closes, and whether there is no other type of parenthesis after it.
If it does, repeat the process until the string is empty.
If the string is not empty in the end of the process, or you find a different kind of parenthesis - it means it is not balanced.

example:

`([[{}]])`

the last opening is `{`, so look for `}`, after you find it- delete it from the string and continue with:
`([[]])`

etc.

if the string looks like that:

`([[{]}])`

so after you find the last open `({)` - you see there is parenthesis from a different kind `(])` before the closing parenthesis - so it is not balanced.

worst case complexity: `O(n^2)`

Answer (score 2):

I assume that, for pedagogical purposes, it would be best to show a simple algorithm that they might actually have come up with themselves? If so, then I think a very intuitive algorithm is to just remove occurrences of `()` until there aren't any more to remove:

```
boolean isBalancedParens(String s) {
    while (s.contains("()")) {
        s = s.replace("()", "");
    }
    return s.isEmpty();
}
```

Under reasonable assumptions about the performance of the various methods called, this takes worst-case *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>) time and *O*(*n*) extra space.

Answer (score 0):

If your students are already familiar with recursion, here's a simple idea: look at the first parenthesis, find all matching closing parentheses, and for each of these pairs, recurse with the substring inside them and the substring after them; e.g.:

```
input:        "{(){[]}()}[]"  
option 1:      ^     ^  
recurse with: "(){[]" and "()}[]"  

              "{(){[]}()}[]"  
option 2:      ^        ^  
recurse with: "(){[]}()" and "[]"
```

If the input is an empty string, return true. If the input starts with a closing parenthesis, or if the input does not contain a closing parenthesis matching the first parenthesis, return false.

```js
function balanced(input) {
    var opening = "{([", closing = "})]";
    if (input.length == 0)
        return true;
    var type = opening.indexOf(input.charAt(0));
    if (type == -1)
        return false;
    for (var pos = 1; pos < input.length; pos++) { // forward search
        if (closing.indexOf(input.charAt(pos)) == type) {
            var inside = input.slice(1, pos);
            var after = input.slice(pos + 1);
            if (balanced(inside) && balanced(after))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
document.write(balanced("{(({[][]}()[{}])({[[]]}()[{}]))}"));
```

Using forward search is better for concatenations of short balanced substrings; using backward search is better for deeply nested strings. But the worst case for both is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

This problem raises a number of interesting questions in algorithm analysis which are possibly at too high a level for your class, but were fun to think about. I sketch the worst-case and expected runtimes for all the algorithms, which are somewhere between log-linear and quadratic.

The only exponential time algorithm I could think of was the equivalent of Bogosort: generate all possible balanced strings until you find one which matches. That seemed to weird even for a class exercise. Even weirder would be the modified Bogocheck, which only generates all ()-balanced strings and uses some cleverness to figure out which actual parenthesis to use in the comparison. (If you're interested, I could expand on this possibility.)

In most of the algorithms presented here, I use a procedure called "scan maintaining paren depth". This procedure examines characters one at a time in the order specified (forwards or backwards) maintaining a total count of observed open parentheses (of all types) less observed close parentheses (again, of all types). When scanning backwards, the meaning of "open" and "close" are reversed. If the count ever becomes negative, the string is not balanced and the entire procedure can immediately return failure.

Here are two algorithms which use constant space, both of which are worst-case quadratic in string length.

***Algorithm 1: Find matching paren***

> Scan left-to-right. For each close encountered, scan backwards starting with the close maintaining paren depth. When the paren depth reaches zero, compare the character which caused the depth to reach 0 with the close which started the backwards scan; if they don't match, immediately fail. Also fail if the backwards scan hits the beginning of the string without the paren depth reaching zero.
>
> If the end of the string is reached without failure being detected, the string is balanced.

***Algorithm 2: Depthwise scan***

> Set `depth` to 1.
>
> LOOP: Scan left-to-right from the first character, maintaining paren depth. If an open is encountered and the paren depth is incremented to `depth`, remember the open. If the paren depth is `depth` and a close is encountered, check to see if it matches the remembered open; if it does not, fail immediately.
>
> If the end of the string is reached before any open is remembered, report success. If the end of the string is reached and the last remembered open was never matched by a close, report failure. Otherwise, increment `depth` and repeat the LOOP.

---

Both of the above have worst case (quadratic) performance on a completely nested string `((…()…))`. However, the average time complexity is trickier to compute.

Each loop in Algorithm 2 takes precisely &Theta(N) time. If the total paren depth of the string is not 0 or there is any point in the string where the cumulative paren depth is negative, then failure will be reported in the first scan, taking linear time. That accounts for the vast majority of strings if the inputs are randomly selected from among all strings containing parenthesis characters. Of the strings which are not trivially rejected -- that is, the strings which would match if all opens were replaced with `(` and all closes with `)`, including strings which are correctly balanced -- the expected number of scans is the expected maximum parenthesis depth of the string, which is Θ(log N) (proving this is an interesting exercise, but I think it's not too difficult), so the total expected time is Θ(N log N).

Algorithm 1 is rather more difficult to analyse in the general case, but for completely random strings it seems safe to guess that the first mismatch will be found in expected linear time. I don't have a proof for this, though. If the string is actually balanced, success will be reported at the termination of the scan, and the work performed is the sum of the span lengths of each pair of balanced parentheses. I believe this is approximately Θ(N log N), but I'd like to do some analysis before committing to this fact.

---

Here is an algorithm which is guaranteed to be O(N log N) for any input, but which requires Θ(N) additional space:

***Algorithm 3: Sort matching pairs***

> Create an auxiliary vector of length N, whose i<sup>th</sup> element is the 2-tuple consisting of the cumulative paren depth of the character at position `i`, and the index `i` itself. The paren depth of an open is defined as the paren depth just before the open is counted, and the paren depth of a close is the paren depth just after the close is counted; the consequence is that matching open and close have the same paren depth.
>
> Now sort the auxiliary vector in ascending order using lexicographic comparison of the tuples. Any O(N log N) sorting algorithm can be used; note that a stable sort is not necessary because all the tuples are distinct. [Note 1].
>
> Finally iterate over the sorted vector, selecting two elements at a time. Reject the string if the two elements do not have the same depth, or are not a matching pair of open and close (using the index in the tuple to look up the character in the original string).
>
> If the entire sorted vector can be scanned without failure, then the string was balanced.

---

Finally, a regex-based solution, because everyone loves regexes. :) This algorithm destroys the input string (unless a copy is made), but requires only constant additional storage.

***Algorithm 4: Regex to the rescue!***

> Do the following search and replace until the search fails to find anything: (I wrote it for sed using Posix BREs, but in case that's too obscure, the pattern consists precisely of an alternation of each possible matched open-close pair.)
>
> ```
>    s/()\|[]\|{}//g
> ```
>
> When the above loop terminates, if the string is not empty then it was not originally balanced; if it is empty, it was.

Note the `g`, which means that the search-and-replace is performed across the entire string on each pass. Each pass will take time proportional to the remaining length of the string at the beginning of the pass, but for simplicity we can say that the cost of a pass is O(N). The number of passes performed is the maximum paren depth of the string, which is Θ(N) in the worst case, but has an expected value of Θ(log N). So in the worst case, the execution time is Θ(N<sup>2</sup>) but the expected time is Θ(N log N).

#### Notes

1. An O(N) stable counting sort on the paren depth is possible. In that case, the total algorithm would be O(N) instead of O(N log N), but that wasn't what you wanted, right? You could also use a stable sort just on the paren depth, in which case you could replace the second element of the tuple with the character itself. That would still be O(N log N), if the sort was O(N log N).

Answer (score -1):

(input.length)>>>
}>>{Strongest}
)Θ(N log N)
)0(N²)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).